# Visual Studio Errors

Tags: visual-studio, error-handling

I have a problem with visual studio. I get these two errors every time I try to compile any project.

Any help how I could resolve this or should I just re-install it ?

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol *WinMain@16 referenced in
>   function*__tmainCRTStartup
>   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: Try running visual studio as administrator? (out of the top of my hat) :)

Comment: You should give more infos, what kind of project, minimal source code producing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do some changed in your setting like this:

> Project properties -> C/C++ -> Linker -> System -> SubSystem: Console
>   (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)

Comment: Thank you so much, I re-installed visual studio again and it gave the same two errors but your solution is perfect once I did it the two errors disappeared. (y)